# Why Is This Noun in the Singular?

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, plural, agreement

I'm reading LLPSI, chapter 20 "Parentes" (skipping ahead quite a few chapters, just for a peek and to see how much I can understand from a more advanced chapter).

The third sentence reads:

> Cūnae sunt lectulus īnfantis.

Why is ***lectulus*** (and the attached genitive *īnfantis*) in the singular, in apparent number mismatch with *cūnae sunt*?

Is it because *lectulus īnfantis* represents some **single**, abstract "concept of little bed" that all cribs are?
Should it be transltaed into English as "Cribs are an infant's bed", in a similar vibe as "dogs are a man's best friend"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because [*cunae, -arum,* f](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcunae), is the word for a single crib. The singular *cuna* is never used. This is similar to how *castra* is a single camp. Such a word is called a *plurale tantum* (plural: *pluralia tantum*).

(English also has a few of these, like *scissors, glasses* or *trousers*.)

Comment: I see. So it's like saying "Scissors are a tool (singular)" or "Trousers are a garment (singular)" in English.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yep!

Comment: You should mention like _glasses (for the optic instrument)_. Otherwise, it is quite confusing as one could very well have a single glass of water.

Comment: Oddly enough, Spanish uses _cuna_ (in the singular) to refer to a single crib; I guess that's what threw me off.