# Grammatical number agreement in this sentence

Tags: adjective, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, plural, agreement

This sentence corresponds to line 57 from chapter XIII of the 2003 edition of *Lingua latina per se illustrata. Familia Romana*:

> Diēs mēnsis prīmus 'kalendae' nōminātur.

If the adjective *primus* is singular, *diēs* should be interpreted as a singular noun. But, if the word *kalendae* is plural, I cannot understand why *diēs primus* is singular. Shouldn't it be *diēs primi* instead?

Comment: I forgot about the verb in my question that, with a plural subject, should also be in plural (that is, *nōmināntur*.

Comment: Here's a related question, but with the numbers switched: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21034/why-is-this-noun-in-the-singular/

Comment: Yes, @cmw: it's included in the anwser.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that edit at first. I'll delete it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this sentence, "dies mensis primus" is one noun phrase, serving as the sentence's subject ("the first day of the month"), "nominatur" is the verb, and "kalendae" is what the first day of the month is called. Recurring days of the calendar are plurale tantum in Latin, so the name of the day happens to be plural, but this doesn't really affect the structure of the sentence.

As for why the verb is singular and not plural, even in English you would say "the first day of the month is called 'calends'", not *"the first day of the month are called 'calends'".

[There is a related question about something similar going in the other direction for pluralia tantum.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21034/why-is-this-noun-in-the-singular?rq=1)

Comment: So, the reason why the subject and the verb are singular is that *kalendae* is a plurale tantum noun? Is this kind of construction usual with other pluralia tantum nouns?

Comment: The form of "dies mensis primus [...] nominatur" isn't really affected by what is on the other end of the verb. With that said, I am having a hard time imagining why a plural noun or name would be on the other end of that construction if it's not a plurale tantum, so yes and no to your question.

Comment: The sentence in the other question is indeed a good example for the question in my previous comment.